# Whats should be TRACE response of an API (if it is not allowed on server)?

Tags: web-application, http, web-service, api

I am testing a website and noticed that when I change the `GET` method of the API request to `TRACE`, it returns an error `405-Method not allowed` in Burp repeater. That's fine.

The problem is, lots of other information is also coming in response like below:

---

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Expires: 0
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=******************; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
MS-Node-Instance: MS_node_1.8100
MS-Node-Instance: MS_node_1.8100
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';font-src 'self' data:; img-src 'self' data: https: blob:; connect-src 'self' wss:;
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';font-src 'self' data:; img-src 'self' data: https: blob:; connect-src 'self' wss:;
Date: Mon, *********** GMT
Allow: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Does this constitute as a vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

The information that you've listed as coming back with the `405` response code appears to be a standard set of Web server headers.

The server giving that information back isn't generally, in and of itself, a security vulnerability as this is all information that servers need to provide to clients to allow their operation.

There's a couple of odd responses in there however, which don't seem ideal and could be worth querying with the application owner

- Several of the headers are repeated.  This could cause issues if changes are made to the system which generates one of those two sets of headers, as the browser (or other user agent) might get confused by differening headers
- The content security policy in use isn't ideal, as it includes items like `unsafe-eval` and `unsafe-inline` which aren't great for security.